# According to Catholicism what happens after Death on the General Judgment Day?

Tags: catholicism, death, judgment

At the General Judgment Day what happens?

Do we recognise each other in the same relationships as we had on earth?

I am very confused and have not been able to find a simple answer in Catholic teaching.

What have Catholic theologians written on this subject?

Comment: @KenGraham Good point, thanks!  Mezz, welcome!

Comment: If you haven't already done so, you should read Matthew 25:31-46, where Christ describes the general judgment.

Answer (score 2):

## Particular & General Judgements

The *[Catechism of the Council of Trent](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/trentc.htm)*, [discussing Article 8 of the Creed ("From thence He shall come to judge the living and the dead")](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/ApostlesCreed07.shtml), explains the difference between one's particular judgement and the general judgement:

> The first [i.e., one's particular judgement] takes place when each one of us departs this life; for then he is instantly placed before the judgment­ seat of God, where all that he has ever done or spoken or thought during life shall be subjected to the most rigid scrutiny. This is called the particular judgment.
>
> The second [i.e., general judgement] occurs when on the same day and in the same place all men shall stand together before the tribunal of their Judge, that in the presence and hearing of all human beings of all times each may know his final doom and sentence. The announcement of this judgment will constitute no small part of the pain and punishment of the wicked; whereas the good and just will derive great reward and consolation from the fact that it will then appear what each one was in life. This is called the general judgment.

## Human Relationships

> *Do we recognise each other in the same relationships as we had on earth?*

The marriage relationship ceases at death:

> [Matt 22:30](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=47&ch=22&l=30-#x)
> For in the resurrection they shall neither marry nor be married, but shall be as the angels of God in heaven.